# Combine column types defined in dcolumn with tabularx, part 2

Tags: tables, tabularx, dcolumn

This is a follow-up on [another question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/combine-column-types-defined-in-dcolumn-with-tabularx). I am trying to combine the `dcolumn` package with `tabularx` (or `tabular*`for that matter) so the table spans the width I specify, columns are evenly spaced, and cells are aligned by the decimal point.

Here's what I have now[image]

The trick suggested in an answer from that other question was to use the 'D' column in the `tabularx` environment, and then an 'X' column inside `\multicolumn`s in the first rows of the table. That worked fine in the example given on that question. But now I have a long text in this `\multicolumn`. The 'X' column seems to "ignore" the number of columns the `\multicolumn` is meant to span. Changing the 'X' by a 'c' prevents the cell to break, like so:[image]

I suppose one solution is to use a 'p' column. But specifying the column width defeats the purpose IMHO, unless there is an automatic way of doing that -- I tried to get some inspiration [from the answer to this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31205/wrapping-column-text-using-multicolumn-and-tabularx) but didn't go very far.

Any thoughts on how to get the text to span the two columns?

EDIT: here's the basic idea of what I think would be ideal. By declaring `\tracingtabularx`, tabularx will print the optimal column widths. So I just used the 'X' column in a first go, saw the what tabularx echoed in my log file, multiplied that by 2 and changed the X column by a 'p' column with the calculated width. Of course, it makes no sense to actually do this by hand. What I want is to get tabularx to do it for me.

Here's the code to generate the tables above:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

% TABLE 1
\noindent
The width of the text block is indicated by this horizontal rule:
\hrule

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{ multicolumn\{2\}\{X\}\{text\} }
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

\toprule
                  & \mc{1}{X}{}       & \mc{2}{X}{A very long text that should span two columns, not one. 'X' doesn't do the trick.}  \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{(1)}    & \mc{1}{Z}{(2)} & \mc{1}{Z}{(3)}   \\ \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{Median} & \mc{1}{Z}{Low} & \mc{1}{Z}{High}  \\ \midrule 
 bla bla bla      &      2.74         &        31.0    &   1.2            \\ 
 ble ble ble ble  &     31.81         &         1.14   &  11.10           \\ 

 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

% TABLE 2
\noindent
The width of the text block is indicated by this horizontal rule:
\hrule

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{ multicolumn\{2\}\{c\}\{text\} }
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

\toprule
                  & \mc{1}{X}{}       & \mc{2}{c}{A very long text that should be wrapped. 'p' would defeat the purpose.}  \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{(1)}    & \mc{1}{Z}{(2)} & \mc{1}{Z}{(3)}   \\ \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{Median} & \mc{1}{Z}{Low} & \mc{1}{Z}{High}  \\ \midrule 
 bla bla bla      &      2.74         &        31.0    &   1.2            \\ 
 ble ble ble ble  &     31.81         &         1.14   &  11.10           \\ 

 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by giving a little help to `tabularx`; since you want to span two equally wide columns, you tell LaTeX that the natural width is twice the reserved width, plus twice the `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

% TABLE 1
\noindent
The width of the text block is indicated by this horizontal rule:
\hrule

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{multicolumn\{2\}\{X\}\{text\} }
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

\toprule
                  & \mc{1}{X}{}       & 
  \mc{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X}{%
    A very long text that should span two columns, not one.
    `X' does the trick, with a little help.} \\
\cmidrule{3-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{(1)}    & \mc{1}{Z}{(2)} & \mc{1}{Z}{(3)}   \\
\cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{Median} & \mc{1}{Z}{Low} & \mc{1}{Z}{High}  \\
\midrule 
bla bla bla      &      2.74         &        31.0    &   1.2            \\ 
ble ble ble ble  &     31.81         &         1.14   &  11.10           \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the long line in a \parbox works for me

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

% TABLE 1
\noindent
The width of the text block is indicated by this horizontal rule:
\hrule



\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{ multicolumn\{2\}\{c\}\{text\} }
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

\toprule
                  & \mc{1}{X}{}       & \mc{2}{c}{\parbox{.5\columnwidth}{A very long text that should be wrapped. 'p' would defeat the purpose.}}  \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{(1)}    & \mc{1}{Z}{(2)} & \mc{1}{Z}{(3)}   \\ \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
                  & \mc{1}{Z}{Median} & \mc{1}{Z}{Low} & \mc{1}{Z}{High}  \\ \midrule 
 bla bla bla      &      2.74         &        31.0    &   1.2            \\ 
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's sort of equivalent to using the 'p' column; unless there is some way of automatically calculating the width of those two columns, that's something I'd avoid if possible.