# combine tabularx and dcolumn and define column width in dcolumn

Tags: arrays

**Problem description**
I am trying to combine the tabularx and dcolumn usepackage in LaTex to format my table. My aim is to create a table that;

1. stretches the width of the text
2. has fixed (2cm) column width for columns with numerical data (i.e. column 2-4).
3. aligns the numerical data around the decimal point.

By using tabularx with the \textwidth argument the exterior dimensions of the table are correct. I have trouble to combine point 2 & 3. Table 1 has the correct column width for the columns containing the numerical data but they are not aligned around the decimal point. Creating a \newcolumntype with the dcolumn package and inserting it with \multicolumn discards the defined column width (Table 2).

I found two related posts but they are not helping on this specific problem.
[Combine column types defined in dcolumn with tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/combine-column-types-defined-in-dcolumn-with-tabularx)
[dcolumn and tabularx, part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141901/dcolumn-and-tabularx-part-2?lq=1)

All ideas are welcome!
Thanks

**Code**
- MiKTeX 2.9

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%preamble
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{correct table layout (column spacing of column 2, 3, 4)}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | m{2cm} | m{2cm} | m{2cm} |}
\hline
item1   & 3.14  & 12.23 & 1.23\\
\hline
item2   & 31.4  & 0.13  & 74.25\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{correct cell alignment on decimal point}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | m{3cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} |}
\hline
item1   & \multicolumn{1}{| . |}{3.14}  & \multicolumn{1}{ . |}{12.23}  & \multicolumn{1}{| . |}{1.23}\\
\hline
item2   & \multicolumn{1}{| . | }{31.4} & \multicolumn{1}{ . |}{0.13}   & \multicolumn{1}{| . |}{74.25}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it is time to start using `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. It provides `table-column-width` key and is capable of aligning at decimal points.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%preamble
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\sisetup{
table-format = 2.2 ,
table-number-alignment = center ,
table-column-width = 2cm ,
}
\caption{correct table layout (column spacing of column 2, 3, 4) and decimal alignment using \texttt{S} column type}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | S | S | S |}
\hline
item1   & 3.14  & 12.23 & 1.23\\
\hline
item2   & 31.4  & 0.13  & 74.25\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{correct table layout (column spacing of column 2, 3, 4)}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | m{2cm} | m{2cm} | m{2cm} |}
\hline
item1   & 3.14  & 12.23 & 1.23\\
\hline
item2   & 31.4  & 0.13  & 74.25\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]